# Does space affect the result in regex ـــــ java

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex in order to define a set of rules that extract specific information from unstructured resumes.
and this information are:

***Company that applicant worked in or still working***

***role (designation)... ex: software engineer***

***Date (From-To)***

every applicant write his/her employment details in his/her own way. However, some resume have a common style for example :

> 2012- 2014.Dean of the Faculty of Engineering Information Technology/
>   University Name.

so I define this `regex` in order to extract the needed information 
Here my regex:

```
(^[0-9]{4})(-|–|.|_|to) ([0-9]{4})(.*) (of the|at|in) (.*).
```

and this regex was able to extract the information from the above example

```
role:Dean 
company: Faculty of Engineering Information Technology/University Name.
date from: 2012 to :2014 
loyalty: 2 years // this is depend on the extracted date
```

But I have another sample from another resume that have the same style of writing

> 1996-1997, Lecturer in Computer Science Department, Jerusalem open
>   university.

it should give Match but it didn't until I remove the space in the regex then it was able to extract the data 
My question is does the space affect in regex??!!

and how I can fix this so that it could extract the data from both resume regarding of the space in the regex rule??

[Here my demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO1yL4/1#pcre) 
[image: the space is here]

Comment: Space is a char in a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the space affect in regex?

You have determined for yourself that it does.  Space characters are not regex metacharacters, unless you enable the `COMMENTS` option in your pattern.  Ordinarily, they stand for themselves, just like most other characters.

> how I can fix this so that it could extract the data from both resume regarding of the space in the regex rule?

You can apply quantifers such as `?` or `*` to space characters in your regex, just like you can to any other character or group.  So, for example, you might use

```
(^[0-9]{4})(-|–|.|_|to) *([0-9]{4})(.*) (of the|at|in) (.*).
```

Do consider also that you might sometimes have to deal with tab characters, too.  You can use the escape sequence `\s` to match any single whitespace character other than a newline, whether it be a space, a tab, or any other recognized as whitespace by Java.

Comment: Ok.. I got it now sorry if my question was odd but I'm still learning about regex and thanx for the answer :)))

Answer (score 1):

You can use an optional amount of white-space by using `\\s*` instead of a space .  `\\s` means white-space character, and the `*` means zero or more